# Convert JToken To List of objects

Tags: c#, json

I Have json string from site like here:

```
{
"bids": [["6500.12", "0.45054140"],
     ["6500.11", "0.45054140"]],  //[price，size]
 "asks": [["6500.16", "0.57753524"],
     ["6500.15", "0.57753524"]] 
}
```

With the help of Newtonsoft Json I tried to get JToken:

```
var content = JObject.Parse(responce)["data"].Children<JProperty>().FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Name=="asks").Value;
```

Then, I would like to convert this JToken to this object, but can`t understand how to

```
        public class PriceValue
        {
            public string Price { get; set; }

            public string Value { get; set; }
        }

        public List<PriceValue> Sell { get; set; }

        public List<PriceValue> Buy  { get; set; }
```

Comment: You'll probably have to do this manually. `content` can be converted to a `JArray`, but you'll have to manually create a new `PriceValue` and set `Price` to `JArray`'s `First()` element and `Value` to its `Last()` element. Likewise, that `PriceValue` will need to be added to `Sell` or `Buy` manually, apparently by position in array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `JObject` and `JArray`

```
var json = File.ReadAllText(filepath);

var jObject = JObject.Parse(json);

var bids = JArray.Parse(jObject["bids"].ToString());    
var Sell = bids.Select(x => 
                new PriceValue
                {
                    Price = x[0].ToString(),
                    Value = x[1].ToString()
                })
                .ToList();

var asks = JArray.Parse(jObject["asks"].ToString());
var Buy = asks.Select(x =>
                new PriceValue
                {
                    Price = x[0].ToString(),
                    Value = x[1].ToString()
                })
                .ToList();
```